# Hibernate in SpringBoot does not persist all Entities in same transaction

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, transactions

I'm using Hibernate version 5.4.22.Final, with SpringBoot 2.3.5.RELEASE, and using this code:

CONTROLLER:

```
@PostMapping("/insert/{id}")
    public MyReposneEntitiy insertAutoAndSendNotification(@PathVariable("id") int id, @Valid @RequestBody Auto auto)  {
        MyReposneEntitiy e = service.insertAuto(auto, id);
        service.sendNotification(id);
        return e;
    }
```

SERVICE:

```
@Transactional
    public MyReposneEntitiy insertAuto(Auto auto, int id) {

        InfoForAuto info = infoRepo.findById(id).get();
        entityManager.detach(info);
        //this is annotated with @Version, 
        //and it can not be changed if the entity is in Persistence Contexxt
        //that's why I'm detaching first and then save
        info.setVersion(auto.getVersion());
        infoRepo.save(info);

        Person person = personService.createPerson(auto.getPerson());
        Eng eng = engService.createEng(auto.getEng(), person.getId());

        info.setMSDNumber(auto.getMSDNumber());
        info.setStatus(Constants.OK);

        MyReposneEntitiy response = new MyReposneEntitiy ();
        response.setStatus(Constants.OK);
        return response;
    }

    public void sendNotification(int id){
        //some code...
    }
```

CALLED SERVICE METHOD:

```
@Transactional
    public PersonResponse createPerson(PersonInput pesronInput) {...}
    
    @Transactional
    public EngResponse createEng(EngInput engInput, Integer personId) {...}
```

Now, the problem is, when insertAuto() method ends, and I'm in the first line in sendNotification() method (in debugging mode) I check the database and **the "person" and "eng" are created in the database but the info entity is not updated,** but I need it to be updated before I call sendNotification method, and I cant figure out why? Aren't they in the same transaction, and hibernate should either save all entities or save none?

Comment: afaik you cannot modify the version yourself, changes won't be detected nor flushed. Hibernate will control the version. The `@Version` will automatically upgrade after you set the values on the `info` and persist it.

Comment: Actually, no, you can change the version on entity that is not in PC, and on repo.save it should throw an error if versions are different, but actually I found the mistake and it's posted as answer

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I found what the problem was.

When I call "`infoRepo.save(info);`" the save()  method as a return object have the entity that is persisted in Pestistence Context, so all I had to do is `info = infoRepo.save(info);` and now it works as it should.